# Simple iOS NavigationController + PDFViewer leaking 1.2 to 2 Mb of memory at each initialization. (Memory Leak)(Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks

I've started learning Swift and iOS programming and I've written a small app, consisted of a navigationController, a FirstViewController and a SecondViewController.

The FirstViewController is the rootViewController. When app first launches, it lands on this ViewController. In this ViewController I have several buttons for corresponding PDF Documents. Each of these buttons does the following.

Button Tapped ->
1) Create SecondViewController
2) Create PDFViewer
3) Load respective PDF file
4) Push the SecondViewController

And when navigationController's "back" button is clicked, I try to clean up the PDFViewer, it's document and dismiss the SecondViewController.

But I have noticed that, in the debug navigators memory tab, with each cycle (Help button clicked -> PDF viewed -> Back button clicked) apps memory usage approximately increases 1.2 to 2 Mb.

I've tried to be careful with the "retain cycles" but obviously I'm missing something fundamental.

Here is the full code,

```
//  FirstViewController.swift
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var helpButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    helpButton.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(self.helpButtonAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    @objc private func helpButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton?){
        SecondViewController = helperDocViewerViewController()

        SecondViewController.docFileName = sender.currentTitle

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(SecondViewController, animated: true)
    }
}


//  helperDocViewerViewController.swift
import UIKit

class helperDocViewerViewController UIViewController {

    var innerView: helperDocViewerView!

    public var docFileName:String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.innerView = helperDocViewerView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        if docFileName != nil {
            self.helperDocViewerView.setDocument(PDF: docFileName)
        }
        self.view.addSubview(self.innerView)
    }
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        self.innerView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.innerView.cleanUp()
        self.innerView = nil
    }
}

//  helperDocViewerView.swift
import PDFKit
class helperDocViewerView:UIView {

    public var pdfViewer:PDFView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.initPage(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.initPage(frame: frame)
    }

    private func initPage(frame: CGRect){
        pdfViewer = PDFView(frame: frame)
        pdfViewer.autoScales = true
        self.addSubview(pdfViewer)
    }

    public func setDocument(PDF:String) {
        if let documentURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: PDF, withExtension: "pdf"){
            if let document = PDFDocument(url: documentURL) {
                self.pdfViewer.document = document
                self.pdfViewer.minScaleFactor = self.pdfViewer.scaleFactor
                self.pdfViewer.layoutDocumentView()

                self.pdfViewer.goToNextPage(nil)        // autoScales Bug?
                self.pdfViewer.goToFirstPage(nil)
            }
        }
    }
    public func cleanUp(){
        self.pdfViewer.removeFromSuperview()
        self.pdfViewer.document = nil
        self.pdfViewer = nil
        self.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

What do you think is causing the memory leak?

P.S.: I'm using Xcode v9.2, Swift v4 and iOS Simulator v10.0 on an High Sierra v10.13.2 iMac

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would run some profilers to know more about what's going on, and running the static analyzer on my code.

one or two megs it's not a lot of memory usage when you are showing PDF Documents on screen. PDF is a complex binary format.

Finding memory leaks:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/FindingLeakedMemory.html

if you wish to know more about PDF Standard. 
http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf